# split a movie into two parts an then concatenate one of the movie with another movie

Tags: objective-c, video, ios6

I am working on an ios6 app in which I have to split a movie into two parts, take one part of it and then concatenate it with other movie clip. 
I tried ffmpeg but could not compile ffmpeg, is there any other way to do this?

Can any one help me out if you have any solution to this problem

Thanks in advance

Comment: ffmpeg is LGPL which means that using it in iOS apps without releasing your source code is legally dubious (as dynamic libraries are not allowed on iOS and dynamic libraries are the only way to use LGPL code without contaminating your own). Using Apple frameworks is one way but you will be limited in the formats which you can handle.

Answer (score 1):

you use the AVMutableComposition class.

see this: [How to combine video clips with different orientation using AVFoundation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575128/how-to-combine-video-clips-with-different-orientation-using-avfoundation)

as well as multiple other answers here on SO that show how to use the class

Comment: thanks Daij-Djan. it works fine for me but one of two video orientation is always upside down.