# Exporting mp4 through AVAssetExportSession fails

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avassetexportsession

I start saying that I spent a lot of time searching through documentation, posts here and somewhere else, but I can't figure out the solution for this problem.

I'm using `AVAssetExportSession` for exporting an `.mp4` file stored in a `AVAsset` instance.
What I do is:

- I check the `isExportable` property of `AVAsset`
- I then get an array of `exportPresets` compatible with the `AVAsset` instance
- I take the `AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080`, or, if not existing I try to export the media with `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` (FYI, 100% of times, the preset I need is always contained in the list, but I tried also the passthrough option and it doesn't work anyway)

The `outputFileType` is `AVFileTypeMPEG4` and I tried also by assigning the `.mp4` extension to the file, but nothing makes it work.
I always receive this error

> Error Domain=AVFoundationErrorDomain Code=-11838 "Operation Stopped"
>   UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x600000658c30 {Error
>   Domain=NSOSStatusErrorDomain Code=-12109 "(null)"},
>   NSLocalizedFailureReason=The operation is not supported for this
>   media., NSLocalizedDescription=Operation Stopped}

Below is the code I'm using

```
func _getDataFor(_ item: AVPlayerItem, completion: @escaping (Data?) -> ()) {
    guard item.asset.isExportable else {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }

    let compatiblePresets = AVAssetExportSession.exportPresets(compatibleWith: item.asset)
    var preset: String = AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough
    if compatiblePresets.contains(AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080) { preset = AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080 }

    guard
        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: item.asset, presetName: preset),
        exportSession.supportedFileTypes.contains(AVFileTypeMPEG4) else {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }

    var tempFileUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("temp_video_data.mp4", isDirectory: false)
    tempFileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: tempFileUrl.path)

    exportSession.outputURL = tempFileUrl
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    let startTime = CMTimeMake(0, 1)
    let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(startTime, item.duration)
    exportSession.timeRange = timeRange

    exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
        print("\(exportSession.error)")
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: tempFileUrl)
        _ = try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: tempFileUrl)
        completion(data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Seems like converting the `AVAsset` instance in a `AVMutableComposition` did the trick. If, please, anyone knows the reason why this works let me know.

This is the new `_getDataFor(_:completion:)` method implementation

```
func _getDataFor(_ item: AVPlayerItem, completion: @escaping (Data?) -> ()) {
    guard item.asset.isExportable else {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }

    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let compositionVideoTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    let compositionAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))

    let sourceVideoTrack = item.asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo).first!
    let sourceAudioTrack = item.asset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeAudio).first!
    do {
        try compositionVideoTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, item.duration), of: sourceVideoTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
        try compositionAudioTrack.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero, item.duration), of: sourceAudioTrack, at: kCMTimeZero)
    } catch(_) {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }

    let compatiblePresets = AVAssetExportSession.exportPresets(compatibleWith: composition)
    var preset: String = AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough
    if compatiblePresets.contains(AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080) { preset = AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080 }

    guard
        let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: preset),
        exportSession.supportedFileTypes.contains(AVFileTypeMPEG4) else {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }

    var tempFileUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0].appendingPathComponent("temp_video_data.mp4", isDirectory: false)
    tempFileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: tempFileUrl.path)

    exportSession.outputURL = tempFileUrl
    exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeMPEG4
    let startTime = CMTimeMake(0, 1)
    let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(startTime, item.duration)
    exportSession.timeRange = timeRange

    exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
        print("\(tempFileUrl)")
        print("\(exportSession.error)")
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: tempFileUrl)
        _ = try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: tempFileUrl)
        completion(data)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Dincer, I'm sorry, I didn't try it on iOS11 so far, I stopped to work on that project

Comment: Yes, this is very strange but using a composition solves the problem.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 5:**

```
import Foundation
import AVKit

func getDataFor(_ asset: AVAsset, completion: @escaping (Data?) -> ()) {
    
    guard asset.isExportable,
          let sourceVideoTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .video).first,
          let sourceAudioTrack = asset.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first else {
              completion(nil)
              return
          }
    
    let composition = AVMutableComposition()
    let compositionVideoTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .video, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
    let compositionAudioTrack = composition.addMutableTrack(withMediaType: .audio, preferredTrackID: CMPersistentTrackID(kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid))
            
    do {
        try compositionVideoTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration), of: sourceVideoTrack, at: .zero)
        try compositionAudioTrack?.insertTimeRange(CMTimeRangeMake(start: .zero, duration: asset.duration), of: sourceAudioTrack, at: .zero)
    } catch {
        completion(nil)
        return
    }
    
    let compatiblePresets = AVAssetExportSession.exportPresets(compatibleWith: composition)
    var preset = AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough
    let preferredPreset = AVAssetExportPreset1920x1080
    if compatiblePresets.contains(preferredPreset) {
        preset = preferredPreset
    }
    
    let fileType: AVFileType = .mp4

    guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(asset: composition, presetName: preset),
          exportSession.supportedFileTypes.contains(fileType) else {
              completion(nil)
              return
          }
    
    let tempFileUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("temp_video_data")
    
    exportSession.outputURL = tempFileUrl
    exportSession.outputFileType = fileType
    let startTime = CMTimeMake(value: 0, timescale: 1)
    let timeRange = CMTimeRangeMake(start: startTime, duration: asset.duration)
    exportSession.timeRange = timeRange
    
    exportSession.exportAsynchronously {
        print(tempFileUrl)
        print(String(describing: exportSession.error))
        let data = try? Data(contentsOf: tempFileUrl)
        try? FileManager.default.removeItem(at: tempFileUrl)
        completion(data)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Check if you set delegate property for AVURLAsset correctly.

```
[self.playerAsset.resourceLoader setDelegate:self queue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
```

And conform to AVAssetResourceLoaderDelegate protocol.
That is all you need to do.

Comment: AVURLAsset.`resourceLoader` should be unrelated to `AVAssetExportSession` (which works with any AVAsset, not just AVURLAsset)

Comment: Although this makes zero sense, this is literally all you have to do.  Set the delegate on the asset resource loader to self and conform to the protocol.  You do not even have to implement any methods or anything.

Comment: Do not know why it work for me, but in my case exportAsynchronously method got failed until I set up delegate and on main queue also important thing. Maybe some version bug

Comment: @panychyk.dima, It worked for me as well. I used it in swift like this:   asset.resourceLoader.setDelegate(self, queue: .main)

Answer (score 4):

I had this same issue because I was adding an audio track to a video without audio.  Removing the audio track fixed it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56729461/video-with-no-audio-crashes-app-on-avmutablecomposition

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem because the `Microphone` permission was off/denied. Once I set turned it on this error went away.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by removing the `CompositionTrack` with media type `.audio` and empty `segments` from the `AVMutableComposition`

```
if let audioTrack = exportComposition.tracks(withMediaType: .audio).first,
    audioTrack.segments.isEmpty {
        exportComposition.removeTrack(audioTrack)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, when I try to `ExportSession` with `AVAssetExportPresetPassthrough` always fail and in my case I can't use another preset because I must have the same resolution like at origin video

I fixed

```
let asset = AVAsset(url: originUrl)
let videoTrack = asset.tracks( withMediaType: .video ).first! as AVAssetTrack

let videoComposition = AVMutableVideoComposition()
videoComposition.renderSize = CGSize(
       width: videoTrack.naturalSize.width, 
       height: videoTrack.naturalSize.height
)
videoComposition.frameDuration = CMTime(
       value: 1, 
       timescale: videoTrack.naturalTimeScale
)
        
let transformer = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction(
       assetTrack: videoTrack 
)
transformer.setOpacity(1.0, at: CMTime.zero)
        
let instruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionInstruction()
instruction.timeRange = timeRange
instruction.layerInstructions = [transformer]
videoComposition.instructions = [instruction]

guard let exportSession = AVAssetExportSession(
       asset: asset, 
       presetName: AVAssetExportPresetMediumQuality
) else {
       return handleFailure(error: .mediaSavingError, completion: completion)
}
        
exportSession.videoComposition = videoComposition
exportSession.outputURL = outputUrl
exportSession.outputFileType = .mp4
exportSession.timeRange = timeRange

exportSession.exportAsynchronously { [weak self] in 
    "your code"
}
```

Forks great for me, and it's saved the same resolution as video before