# How to combine portrait and landscape assets in AVMutableComposition for preview

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition, avasset

I have `AVAssets` that are portrait and landscape orientation. When I play them one at a time with the `AVPlayer` they play with the correct orientation. So the `AVPlayer` is reading each video's `AVAssetTrack` `preferredTransform` and adjusting accordingly.

On the other hand, when I add a portrait asset to a `AVMutableComposition` it shows up sideways. Presumably this is because the `AVMutableCompositionTrack` just has a default `preferredTransform` of `CGAffineTransformIdentity`.

What I want is for my `AVMutableComposition` to honor the `preferredTransform` of assets I add to it so everything shows up correctly.

*Part 2*

I know I can perform a video rotation by supplying compositing instructions (`AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstructions`) to an `AVAssetExportSession`, for example as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575128/how-to-combine-video-clips-with-different-orientation-using-avfoundation). But I don't want to export the video yet.

Is `AVAssetExportSession` the only class that takes `AVMutableVideoComposition` as an input?

*Part 3*

I'm trying to play a preview of the video I'm about to export, and the only compositing operation is a transform to either portrait or landscape. So I think there should be a lighter-weight way to do this, without running an `AVAssetExportSession` every time the user changes the mutable composition. Is this right?

*Aside*

As an aside, I guess I'm not understanding why `AVMutableVideoComposition` is not itself a descendent of `AVAsset` like `AVMutableComposition` is. Then you could just play the compostion directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   AVPlayerItem * item item = [[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:[collageComposition mutableCopy]];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(itemDidFinishPlaying:) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:item];
item.videoComposition = [collageVideoComposition mutableCopy];
[item setSeekingWaitsForVideoCompositionRendering:NO];
item.audioMix = audioMix;
self.previewPlayer = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:item];
```

that's all you need for a preview. If you use `animationTool` in your `AVMutableVideoComposition` AVPlayer don't suport it. Use AVSynchronizedLayer for this purpose.

Comment: what is **audioMix** , can you explain?

Comment: `AVAudioMix` is used for custom audio processing, `AVPlayerItem` property.
[Here more](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1388037-audiomix?language=objc)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, `AVPlayerItem` has a `videoComposition` property. Modifying the `AVPlayerItem` would be appropriate for a preview display.