# Merging two clips with different orientations using AVMutableCompasition / AVFoundation

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avmutablecomposition

How can I merge two clips with different orientations using an `AVMutableCompasition` and `AVAssetTracks`? It works when the orientations are correct, but if I use something like a Square cropped video the export just fails with an "Unknown Error".

Comment: Though it is in objc, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6575128/how-to-combine-video-clips-with-different-orientation-using-avfoundation